# Any Way of Knowing What This Javascript Code Does?

Tags: javascript

I've been noticing some strange things going on with my websites so I have been inspecting my files when I came across this:

```
if( typeof document.getElementsByClassName != 'function' ) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(classname) {
        var node = document.body;
        var a = [];
        var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
        var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
            if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
                return a;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what this might be doing?

Comment: describe strange behavior?

Comment: I believe that if `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't a function(?) it's declaring another function for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a simple implementation of `document.getElementsByClassName` method of `document` object. It's a standart method but is not defined in older browsers(like older IE versions).

```
if( typeof document.getElementsByClassName != 'function' ) {
```

This part checks if type of the method is not a function(so not defined) and later on defines it if so.

With this method you can select DOM elements from your document using class name, like this

```
<div class="box"></div>
document.getElementsByClassName('box')
```

Comment: how do i know if its safe to remove? what should i look for?

Comment: you should look for document.getElementsByClassName calls in your code. This code defines this method. But I will suggest not to remove this piece of code as it's a shim for missing functionality and not a harmful code